# Font Awesome icons are not loading with Integrity attribute

Tags: html, css, angular, font-awesome

I am using angular 6 application. In the index.html file, we have font awesome reference like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-oqVuAfXRKap7fdgcCY5uykM6+R9GqQ8K/uxy9rx7HNQlGYl1kPzQho1wx4JwY8wC" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Now, I am trying update the fontawesome to 5.10.2 versionc like:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-oqVuAfXRKap7fdgcCY5uykM6+R9GqQ8K/uxy9rx7HNQlGYl1kPzQho1wx4JwY8wC" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

The font awesome icons are not displaying and I am getting the exception in the browser's console as:

```
Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute for resource 'https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.2/css/all.css' with computed SHA-256 integrity 'zmfNZmXoNweWBMcemUOo1XdsUGFfcasdasda0ihGGLYdgtJS3KCr/l0='. The resource has been blocked.
```

The font awesome icons are displaying fine when I remove the integrity attribute as:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.2/css/all.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

What am I doing wrong? Please suggest. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you modifying in index.html? There is npmjs: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-font-awesome, https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome, https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome

Answer (score 2):

You are using same integrity value for both 5.1 and 5.10.

5.10 should be different then 5.1. So find the integrity value for 5.10 then it should work

Comment: How to change the integrity value, that is my actual issue :-)

Comment: Where you got the CDN URL? there should be a integrity value

Comment: You can get the integrity for any file using a site like https://www.srihash.org/

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are using the wrong integrity value, as has been [said already by @Ravin Singh D](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57766472/2862945). Use the [CDN Picker](https://fontawesome.com/account/cdn) to get the correct CDN URLs and integrity key.